# I can't install software-center on Kali

Tags: apt

It shows this error

```
oot@kali:~# apt-get install software-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496463/49368

Answer (score 7):

#### Where is `software-center`?

Software center does not exist in Kali Linux any longer, as it has been replaced by the Synaptic package manager. It is an [extremely bad idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244097/add-repositories-in-kali-linux-2-0/244259#244259) to add repositories to your `sources.list` file, so instead you must use Synaptic.

#### Synaptic

To get Synaptic, simply type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install synaptic` into your command line. This will install it. It functions similarly to Software Center.

For more information on Synaptic go to the following link:
http://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/

Answer (score 5):

[`software-center`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center) is available in Ubuntu, not in Kali. You should use Synaptic in Kali.

Comment: `packagekit` is the default package manager under kali2 , http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/packagekit

Comment: @GAD3R PackageKit isn't a package manager, it's an abstract interface above package managers.